# How to create a clone of a String variable?

Tags: java, string

How can the clone of a string variable created?

There is a string variable say str

```
String str = row.getAttribute("Attribute");
```

So how can i copy the value of the attribute in the row to the string so that i can show the value even when the row has been erased from the memory.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to clone an immutable string ?

Comment: Are you talking about the reference to the `String` or the object itself?

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: You've already done it. The string isn't 'erased' with the row.

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
String newString = new String(oldString);
```

But what's your reason to clone an immutable string ?

I do this only when I want to trim the extra hidden chars from the original strings when I got my string by using `substring`.

**Regarding you edit :**

If you do

```
String str = row.getAttribute("Attribute");
```

then `str` will still contain the exact same value even after you destroy `row` or you change the attribute "Attribute" of `row`. You don't need to clone it. The fact that you keep a reference (the variable `str`) to it keeps it safe from garbaging.

Answer (score 1):

In Java the `String` object is immutable. That means it won't change under you and consequently you can safely use the same reference throughout your program.

If you amend a `String` (via appending, trimming etc.) then that creates a new, immutable object. So the concept of cloning is redundant in this scenario.